# How to diagnose SSIS packages locking each-others?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have several SSIS packages doing a few queries and inserting the results in new tables. 
Those SSIS packages are triggered with different parameters values by service broker queues, with max 10 simultaneous operations. (ex : two packages, each of those being called 5 times with 5 different values of a parameter)

When operated separately they only took a few seconds, but when called by the service broker, after a few ran successfull, they start slowing down, then totally stuck.

There are no concurrent read and inserts, the packages all read from the same tables (with nolocks everywhere) but then insert new data in new tables created by the packages. Each package write in its own destination table on which none other package would try to read nor write.

What should I consider modifying in SSIS or investigate in SSMS and/or profiler to diagnose and solve this issue ? I'm not really used to track down locks...

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Interesting. Messages are pushed onto a queue, your activation proc picks up that data, shoves it into a table and then you launch SSIS to do something the data? What version of SQL Server are you running?  `SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('productversion')` Could you update your question with a minimal repro. Screenshots will work for the SSIS package(s). How are you launching the packages - shelling out to DTEXEC or are these in the MSDB?

Comment: Hello, I'm on SQLServer 2016.
I have a temp job that, from time to time read from a table a list of data "streams" and parameters, then for each "stream" push messages into a queue, which triggers a stored procedure that will call, for each stream, 4 SSIS packages with said parameters, then send a message back into the queue, to trigger machine learning algorithms on the data gathered by SSIS.

Comment: Raise it here : http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: `Could you update your question with a minimal repro. Screenshots will work for the SSIS package(s)`

Answer (score 1):

1. I would recommend using [sp_whoisactive](http://whoisactive.com/downloads/) to be sure nothing is blocking.
2. I would also recommend monitoring resources (IO, network, RAM) on target/destination/ETL server(s)
3. Try running different scenarios such as 2 packages and 2 simultaneous operations etc.

Comment: I will try that and come back with my findings. Many thanks.

Comment: Hi again,
Great proc, browsing its documentation made me learn a lot too !

Well, If I read its results well, I don't have any un-shared locks, packages are slowing each other pretty much, but everything is slowly advancing, the execution plans show most of the issue would come from the indices...

Comment: If reorganizing/rebuilding indexes doesn't solve my issues, are there any config to tweak for optimal simulatneous indices reads ?